# Passing parameter with header location

Tags: php

I was assigned to a project and i am trying to figure out something with the following line but i am not able to understand how it works.

```
header("location:".$config['webDir']['root'].'auto_racing');
```

Now that `$config['webDir']['root']` has my virtual host name in it like `http://mylocaltest.local`.

The same code works fine on actual server but on my virtual host that line tries to find page `http://mylocaltest.local/auto_racing` and thats why it throws error `404 not found`

I know this is not a lot of information i have given here but all i want is to understand how the passing parameter works with `header` and why it is trying to find the page `auto_racing`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [session](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php) instead because you would be showing the user's name everytime on the welcome page no matter which page you land at welcome page.

You can set the session on login_check page like:

```
session_start(); // this should be on top of login_check file

// this goes just before redirect line
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

Now on the welcome page, you can show username like:

```
session_start(); // this should be on top of welcome page.
echo `Welcome ` . $_SESSION['username'];
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880359/passing-arguments-via-header-in-php)

Comment: thank you but i don't know how its related to my problem.`auto_racing` is not user but instead its a parameter or sport type in my project. So when i pass `auto_racing` i set all other variables according to that. And for a new user `auto_racing` is default sport type selected.